# Disable all commands to remap them all

Tags: vim

Is it possible to disable/remove all mapping/commands in order to remap them all from scratch?

Comment: WHY WOULD YOU WANT TO DO THAT?

Comment: That's a good thing. Aknowledging your condition is a positive step toward recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable all built-in commands, you have to override them with a *no operation* mapping (`:help <Nop>`), like this:

```
:noremap w <Nop>
```

But, if you intend to remap them later, anyway, there's no need for this, as the remapping will override the command, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the vim help:

```
:mapc[lear]  (nvo modes)
:nmapc[lear] (n mode)
:cmapc[lear] (c mode)
... and so on

Remove ALL mappings from the modes where the map command applies.
```

Comment: Nah it's just for the session, or until you reload your vimrc, or wherever you define mappings.

Comment: I did use these commands, but i'm still able to use `w`, `dw`, etc. Why?

Comment: Good question.  It does say in the help "Warning: this also removes the default mappings"  But it must not pertain to things like motion commands, apparently.

Comment: @Fabricio `w`, `d` and others are not mappings, they are normal-mode commands. Default mappings are default mappings like `<F1>` mapping to help, they are really mappings that are defined in plugins from the vim distribution.

Answer (score 0):

To shed some light on the behavior and documentation of `:mapclear`:

The built-in stuff (e.g. the `w` normal mode movement) is called *commands*. The keys that trigger them can be changed; this is a *mapping*. Vim comes with some plugins and settings enabled out of the box; these are referred to as *default mappings*.